# How to join two tables in PySpark with two conditions in an optimal way

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following two tables in PySpark:

Table A - dfA

```
    | ip_4          | ip           |
    |---------------|--------------|
    | 10.10.10.25   | 168430105    |
    | 10.11.25.60   | 168499516    |
```

And table B - dfB

```
    | net_cidr      | net_ip_first_4 | net_ip_last_4  | net_ip_first | net_ip_last |
    |---------------|----------------|----------------|--------------|-------------|
    | 10.10.10.0/24 | 10.10.10.0     | 10.10.10.255   |  168430080   | 168430335   |
    | 10.10.11.0/24 | 10.10.11.0     | 10.10.11.255   |  168430336   | 168430591   |
    | 10.11.0.0/16  | 10.11.0.0      | 10.11.255.255  |  168493056   | 168558591   |
```

I have joined both tables in PySpark using the following command:

```
dfJoined = dfB.alias('b').join(F.broadcast(dfA).alias('a'),
                               (F.col('a.ip') >= F.col('b.net_ip_first'))&
                               (F.col('a.ip') <= F.col('b.net_ip_last')),
                               how='right').select('a.*, b.*)
```

So I obtain:

```
| ip            | net_cidr      | net_ip_first_4 | net_ip_last_4| ...
|---------------|---------------|----------------|--------------| ...
| 10.10.10.25   | 10.10.10.0/24 | 10.10.10.0     | 10.10.10.255 | ...
| 10.11.25.60   | 10.10.11.0/24 | 10.10.11.0     | 10.10.11.255 | ...
```

The size of the tables makes this option not optimal due to the 2 conditions, I had thought of sorting table B so that it only implies one join condition.

Is there any way to limit the join and take only the first record that matches the join condition? Or some way to make the join in an optimal way?

Table A (number of records) << Table B (number of records)

Thank you!

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? Are you looking for an SQL answer?

Comment: Do you have any clue @Steven?

Comment: It seems to me your desired output is incorrect as the IP `10.11.25.60` is not in `10.10.11.0/24`. That being said, for efficiency reasons you typically try to join the smaller onto the bigger, so that you don't need to shuffle the bigger table. If you're sure all the IPs are covered by the CIDR table, perhaps `join="left"`, followed by a filter could turn out to be much faster (or even just how="inner", but like I said, only if the CIDR table covers all IPs you want). One more option: if you know the formula to compute the fields `net_ip_first` and `net_ip_last`, just use that?